# ArrayFormula which returns the second last matching

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, lookup, array-formulas

I have a table which collects daily readings of a **total score** from many different players. Since it's manual collection via form it may be that some players will add their reading more than once a day, and also can be a day or more without any reading at all.
The structure is very basic 3 columns (Date, Player, Total).

I'm looking for an `ArrayFormula` that will automatically filling in a 4th column with the **daily score** of the specific player. This can achieve by a formula that finds the second-last reading of the specific player and subtract it from its last/current reading.

| Date | Player | Total | Daily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2021 | Player 001 | 1500 | 1500 |
| **17**/10/2021 | Player 007 | 700 | 700 |
| **19**/10/2021 | Player 003 | 700 | 700 |
| 19/10/2021 | Player 005 | 100 | 100 |
| 19/10/2021 | Player 004 | 1100 | 1100 |
| 19/10/2021 | Player 006 | 300 | 300 |
| 19/10/2021 | Player 002 | 900 | 900 |
| **20**/10/2021 | **Player 006** | 900 | 600 |
| **20**/10/2021 | **Player 006** | 1600 | 700 |
| 20/10/2021 | Player 002 | 1100 | 200 |
| 20/10/2021 | Player 005 | 600 | 500 |
| 20/10/2021 | Player 009 | 200 | 200 |
| 21/10/2021 | Player 001 | 1600 | 100 |
| 21/10/2021 | Player 003 | 1000 | 300 |

I found a very interesting solution, but since it's based on `INDIRECT` it can't work with `ArrayFormula`:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-the-last-matching-value-in-google-sheets/

I thought about a different approach, using `VLOOKUP` and limiting the search-range to the rows above the current row, then to find the last matching value in this range (-which is actually the second-last in the whole table), but I can't find a syntax that is working in ArrayFormula.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Pitt
If you provide an example sheet it makes it easier for members to help solve your problem!

Comment: Are dates always consecutive?

Comment: An example sheet added

Comment: This is no longer daily score in your example data. It is the difference with the previous score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer a tentative solution, with the understanding that it's always difficult to write such a formula without the ability to see some actual data and the expected result.

Let's say your data is in A2:C (with headers in A1:C1). Try the following formula in D2 of an otherwise empty Col D:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,C2:C - (VLOOKUP(B2:B&(A2:A-1), SORT({ {"", 0}; {B2:B&A2:A, C2:C} }), 2, TRUE) * (VLOOKUP(B2:B&(A2:A-1), SORT({ {"", 0}; {B2:B&A2:A, B2:B} }), 2, TRUE) = B2:B))))`

To find the second-to-last score per player, `VLOOKUP` looks up a concatenation of each row's player-and-"yesterday" within a `SORT`ed virtual range containing A.) {null, 0} on top of B.) {a concatenation of each row's player-and-date, score}.

Because of the `SORT`, a final parameter of `TRUE` can be used, which means that if an exact match for player-and-"yesterday" is not found, the closest previous match will be returned. The `* VLOOKUP(...)` is there to make sure the previous match is for the same person (because the alphabetical entry prior to each person's earliest date will be someone else's *last* date, except for the first person alphabetically, who will bounce back to the {null, 0}).

However, if your sheet will always have at least one blank row below your data, you can simplify a bit:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,C2:C - (VLOOKUP(B2:B&(A2:A-1), SORT({B2:B&A2:A, C2:C}), 2, TRUE) * (VLOOKUP(B2:B&(A2:A-1), SORT({B2:B&A2:A, B2:B}), 2, TRUE) = B2:B))))`

This is because the bounce-back for the first alphabetical person's first date will find {null, null} for all blank rows, which is equivalent to {null, 0}, all of which will be `SORT`ed earlier than all of your data. So we don't need to include it in the virtual array setup.

If the result is not as expected, please share a minimal set of realistic data with the expected results.

**ADDENDUM** (*per additional comment from OP)*:

If a player may enter more than one score per day, you can use the formula versions below.

If you're not sure you'll always have at least one blank row below your data:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,C2:C - (VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B)-1,"0000"), SORT({ {"", 0}; {B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B),"0000"), C2:C} }), 2, TRUE) * (VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B)-1,"0000"), SORT({ {"", 0}; {B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B),"0000"), B2:B} }), 2, TRUE) = B2:B))))`

If you *are* sure you will always have at least one blank row below your data:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,C2:C - (VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B)-1,"0000"), SORT( {B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B),"0000"), C2:C} ), 2, TRUE) * (VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B)-1,"0000"), SORT( {B2:B&TEXT(ROW(B2:B),"0000"), B2:B} ), 2, TRUE) = B2:B))))`

Both of the above substitute row number for date. They assume, then, that your data will always be entered in the order they occurred in real time, not randomly (i.e., that you will not enter an earlier date's score after a later date's score). If you *will* potentially enter things out of order, this can also be controlled for; but I haven't done so here.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Great—I guess we lucked out.

Comment: Although, it'll not work if a specific player adds more than one reading on the same day.

Comment: That was not mentioned in your post, so I didn't control for it in my original post. See my "ADDENDUM."

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully it clarified now

Comment: See my post's "ADDENDUM."

Comment: The "ADDENDUM" works as charm! (in my case dates are always in ascending order) Huge thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I was still on to catch the update.

Comment: One final note: my "ADDENDUM" formulas account for up to 9,999 rows. If you believe you'll have data running more than that, be sure to change the four instances of `"0000"` to `"00000"` to cover up to 99,999 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    A2:A = "",,
        C2:C
      - IFNA(VLOOKUP(
            MATCH(
              B2:B,
              UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B <> "")),
            )
          * 10^INT(LOG10(ROWS(A2:A)) + 1)
          + ROW(A2:A) - 1,
          SORT(
            {
              SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)) * {10^INT(LOG10(ROWS(A2:A)) + 1), 0};
              FILTER(
                {
                    MATCH(
                      B2:B,
                      UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B <> "")),
                    )
                  * 10^INT(LOG10(ROWS(A2:A)) + 1)
                  + ROW(A2:A),
                  C2:C
                },
                A2:A <> ""
              )
            },
            1, 1
          ),
          2
        ))
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, but same as @ErikTyler solution, it'll not work if a specific player adds more than one reading on the same day.

Comment: @Pitt are you sure? I marked in bold entries by the same player for the same day.

Comment: too many changes to the original question...

Comment: Thanks! it's working now.